My bluetooth state preservation works, but given enough hours of the iphone being locked it fails to reconnect
I am re implementing a BLE manager class from a different code base that didn't have state preservation and restore. It works good, but doesn't reconnect after the phone being locked for an uncertain amount of hours, not even sure how to test that.
Anything I can improve?
class BLEController: NSObject, CBPeripheralDelegate, ObservableObject {

 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral:  CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
 self.connectedPeripheral = nil
 self.isConnecting = false
 self.isConnected = false
 self.isSubscribed = false

 if let e = error {
  let errorCode = (e as NSError).code
  if errorCode == 6 { 
  // save/print error code
   } else if errorCode == 7 { 
   // save/print error code
   } else if errorCode == 14 { 
   // save/print error code
   } else {
   // save/print error code
   }

 connectTo(peripheral: peripheral)

 } else {
    // Disconnected without error which indicates user intent to disconnect
    // Happens when swiping to disconnect
    print("ℹ️ BLE Disconnected: \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown"): User Initiated Disconnect")
  }
    
 }



// Connect to a specific peripheral
 func connectTo(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
 stopScanning()
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.isConnecting = true
  self.lastConnectionError = ""
  self.automaticallyReconnect = true
  }
  if connectedPeripheral != nil {
  print("ℹ️ BLE Disconnecting from: \(connectedPeripheral.name) to connect to \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")")
    disconnectPeripheral()
  }
        
 centralManager?.connect(peripheral)

 // Invalidate any existing timer
 if timeoutTimer != nil {
    timeoutTimer!.invalidate()
 }
 // Use a timer to keep track of connecting peripherals, context to pass the radio name with the timer and the RunLoop to prevent
        // the timer from running on the main UI thread
  let context = ["name": "\(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")"]
  timeoutTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.5, target: self, selector: #selector(timeoutTimerFired), userInfo: context, repeats: true)
  RunLoop.current.add(timeoutTimer!, forMode: .common)
  print("ℹ️ BLE Connecting: \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")")
}


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {

  //I dont even think anything has to go here?? Followed an example.
 let peripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] as? [CBPeripheral]
 let navigationServiceUUIDObject = RavedioServiceCBUUID
 let recoverPeripherals = peripherals?.filter({ (peripheral: CBPeripheral) -> Bool in
    var found = false
    if let services = peripheral.services {
        for service in services {
        if service.uuid == navigationServiceUUIDObject {
      found = true
      break
    }
      }
    }
  return found
  })
  foundPeripherals = recoverPeripherals
}

Or could it be with my peripheral not pinging the app enough?

There are a couple of questionable things in your presented code: you implement CBCentralManagerDelegate functions in your BLEController - which conforms to  CBPeripheralDelegate but not to CBCentralManagerDelegate. Then, your BLEController class has connection states, which cannot handle multiple peripherals trying to connect. You dispatch to the main queue, but you could/should rather specify the queue in the initialiser of the central manager. You stop scanning while connecting to a peripheral. You use optionals where non-optionals are required.  Difficult to tell what's going on.

Hello, there is a method centralManagerDidUpdateState not shown, that helps it conform to ManagerDelegate right? The connection states are used to show the user when it is connected as well as the peripheral (radio) checking if it can send a message or exchange packets. Is there not supposed to be an optional on centralManager?.connect? Or maybe WillRestore, not sure if anything even has to go inside the latter. I agree it looks all over the place though. I was forking an existing project that didn't implement state restoration. It mostly works though somehow? Is didDisconnectPeripheral ok?
